# Extracting grouped layers from psd

Tags: photoshop, layer, psd

I am a developer and working on an application whose designs I have received as a PSD file. But I am totally a beginner in designing. I have installed Photoshop in my computer but have no idea about how to save a layer out of that.

There are buttons in the PSD which I want and I have hidden all other layers except the one I need. Now I want to save it but I am just not able to do it. I have searched on google but could not find any solution.

Comment: Non-programming questions are better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop)

Comment: Instead of roughly downvoting, you can simply notify the OP so he knows for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the layer you want to export
2. Select All (control/command + shift + a) then copy merged (control/command + shift + c)
3. Create a new file (control/command + n) (Edit:)Make sure Preset is set to `Clipboard`, then hit return. It will automatically be the right size of the clipboard
4. Paste (control/command +v) then Save for Web... (control/command + alt + shift +s) and then follow the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Select the layer(s) which you want to save.
2. right click on it (them) and select "Duplicate layer"
3. In the dialogue you get, in the "Document" Drop down list select "New".
4. Now, the selected layer(s) should be in the new document
5. in Menu bar select Image > Trim.
6. select "Transparent pixels" radio button, and check top left bottom right. and press OK.
7. now you can press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S (or File > save for web and devices) to save it in the format you want.

Comment: If he does it that way, the resulting image will be the size of the entire PSD, not the size of the button.

Comment: The new document, by default, is the same size as the clipboard... so one shouldn't need to use Trim.

Comment: i followed above method on 1366 x 768 sized canvas. one layer i selected contained image of 500 x 500. in step 4 i got that layer on a 1366 x 768 canvas so had to use trim to remove the transparent pixels

Comment: The default setting for Photoshop is that the canvas default is the same size as the clipboard. You'll see this as the Preset being set to Clipboard. Either you changed your settings (eg no longer set to clipboard) or had something larger selected.